# How can I use Mockito to mock a method of an instantiated class?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I need to write a test case for this CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImpl service. How can I mock the enrollExtStub.enrollExt() method

```
@Service
public class CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImpl implements CustomerEnrollmentSoapService {


    @Override
    public EnrollExtStub.EnrollExtResponse enrollMember(LoyalHeaders loyalHeaders, EnrollExtStub.Data_type0 enrollMember)  {
        EnrollExtStub enrollExtStub = new EnrollExtStub();

        EnrollExtStub.EnrollExtResponse enrollExtResponse = enrollExtStub.enrollExt(enrollExt, messageHeader);
        return enrollExtResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: This scenario is called mocking method local instantiation. Use powermockito instead of mockito.

Comment: @kswaughs can you put sample code as an answer

Comment: Added my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to do this. Assuming you really want to test this, it looks like generated code, I probably wouldn't test and I test a lot. But, if you do you need a seam. If `EnrollExtStub` is stateless, or calling `enrollExt` on it doesn't change internal data you could make it an autowired bean.

```
@Service
public class CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImpl implements CustomerEnrollmentSoapService {
   @Autowired
   private EnrollExtStub enrollExtStub;

    @Override
    public EnrollExtStub.EnrollExtResponse enrollMember(LoyalHeaders loyalHeaders, EnrollExtStub.Data_type0 enrollMember)  {

        EnrollExtStub.EnrollExtResponse enrollExtResponse = enrollExtStub.enrollExt(enrollExt, messageHeader);
        return enrollExtResponse;
    }
}
```

Then make `EnrollExtStub` a bean

```
@Configuration
public class EnrollExtStubConfig {

    @Bean
    public EnrollExtStub enrollExtStub(){
        return new EnrollExtStub();
    }
}
```

Then in your test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    private EnrollExtStub enrollExtStub;
...
```

Alternatively you could just have it directly call a another class similar to the `EnrollExtStubConfig` where it creates the `EnrollExtStub` and you could mock that class to return your a mock `EnrollExtStub`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImpl.class})
public class CustomerEnrollmentSoapServiceImplTest  {

  @Test
  public void enrollMemberTest() throws Exception {

    EnrollExtStub enrollExtStubMock = PowerMockito.mock(EnrollExtStub.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(EnrollExtStub.class).thenReturn(enrollExtStubMock);

    PowerMockito.when(enrollExtStubMock.enrollExt(Matchers.anyClass(enrollExt.class), Matchers.anyClass(MessageHeader.class))
       .thenReturn(enrollExtResponse);
 }
}
```